# "Replace with File in Git Index" appears disabled

Tags: git, egit

I'm using eclipse with Egit. I'm trying to undo the changes of a single file which has not yet been committed. From what I read, it should be as simple as opening up the Git Staging view, right clicking on the file and selecting "Replace with File in Git Index". However, this options always appears disabled (enabled are only the other two, "Open working tree version" and "Add to git index").

My questions are:

- Why does it appear disabled?
- Is there another, simple way to undo the
  changes in a specific file, which has not yet been committed?

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 (the one bundled with PDT), Egit 1.3.0.201202151440-r on Ubuntu 12.04.

Edit:
It appears that this option is disabled when I have the same project open in PHP perspective. If I close the project from PHP perspective, then the greyed-out options are available (Replace with file in Git index and Replace with file in HEAD revision)

Comment: If the Git Staging view doesn't work, can you try it in the Package Explorer view (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Replace_with_File_in_Git_Index)

Comment: that only gives me "replace with local history" and "previous from local history". The file was changed outside eclipse so this is not really an option (and even if it was, I would prefer it replaced with its original counterpart from git)

Comment: Are you sure this file is actually part of Git history? It is the same case (upper or lowercase) than the one in git? What a `git status` returns in a command line session?

Comment: yes it is. In the git status it appears as "modified". The same happens for any file I change, it's not about a specific one. I can normally commit and push them, or reset the whole repository, I just can't revert one single file

Comment: Ok. which Eclipse version, Egit version, Os version are you using?

Comment: I updated the question, sorry about that, I should have posted this info right from the start

Comment: Egit 1.3 seems a bit old. Any chance to upgrade to 2.2 and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @VonC: I updated to version 2.1 using eclipse's update manager, and it didn't help. However, poking around brought up some new data and I have updated my question accordingly

Comment: Is it related to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317188 ?

Comment: no, it appears not. I have filed a bug report with egit and will post back if anything comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling PDT/Egit seems to fix the problem

Comment: Sounds good to know after all my comments ;) +1. Did you re-install a different and more recent version of PDT/Egit?

Comment: Yes, I installed the most recent available, although there wasn't any changelog entry related. Who knows what was going on...